# Opposite of FOR (loop)

Tags: file, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I got the command:

```
for /f "delims=// tokens=2,4,6" %%a in (memod.txt) do @echo %%a %%b %%c
```

Which work as it shall.
But i need one which does not go through every single line of text, but through a single specific line.

Thank you!

Comment: The Gnu Sed (stream editor) may be valuable if you can use a free downloaded tool.  Exactly how to apply it depends on what you specifically want to do but the command `sed 5!d file.txt` will print line 5 and then extra commands can process the line.

Comment: Do not put "SOLVED" in your title. If an answer solved your question, then accept the answer by clicking the check mark near the upper left corner of the answer. That awards you 2 reputation points, and the answer poster 15 rep points. Only one answer can be accepted. If you solved the problem on your own and none of the existing answers solve the problem, then write your solution as an answer, and then after 2 days you can accept your own answer (you don't get rep points for accepting your own answer)

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "skip=N delims=// tokens=2,4,6" %%a in (memod.txt) do @echo %%a %%b %%c & goto break
:break
```

The `skip=N` option skips over the first N lines; after processing the line N+1 the `goto` break the processing of next lines.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't reveal precisely how you want to select the "specific line" it's difficult to come up with an answer, HOWEVER:

`"delims=//` does NOT select `//` as your separator as you appear to expect, but selects `/` and .

From another question, it appears that your data line contains `"//"` and the `FOR..delims...` syntax regards successive delimiters as one, so it may APPEAR to work - but it would also "work" on a line like `this/is/not/a/target/line/at/all` or `neither///is///this///a///target///line`

Perhaps a structure like

```
for /f "tokens=2,4,6delims=/" %%a in (
 'type memod.txt^|findstr /r ".*//.*//.*" '
  ) do (
 echo %%a %%b %%c&goto skipfor
)
:skipfor
```

or

```
for /f "tokens=2,4,6delims=/" %%a in (
 'type memod.txt^|findstr /r ".*//.*//.*" ^|findstr /v "///" '
  ) do (
 echo %%a %%b %%c&goto skipfor
)
:skipfor
```

may suit.

Comment: I appreciate the comment, while some of the coding is unknown to me, i have seemed to make it work. Thanks.